# unable to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with php script

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I'm starting to spin out now. Too much trial and error has made me rather grumpy.

I am trying to do an INSERT and UPDATE if EXISTS using a loop. I have excluded the loop code from this example to simplify my problem.

Here is the query in my PHP script:

```
function insertrating($ratingid, $rating){
    $link = resdb::connect();
    $r = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO propertyrating (id,name)" 
                            ."VALUES (\'$ratingid\',\'$rating\')\n"
                ."ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE\n"
                ."name = VALUES (name),\n"
                ."description = VALUES (description)\n"
                . "");
    if($r > 0){
        return true;
    }
 }
 $mydbclass = new $dbclass();
 $mydbclass->insertrating('3','3 Star');
```

Table is as follows:
     id int
     name varchar(100)
     description text

I do not want to add description at this stage. Hence no parameters for that column

I have produced the exact same query in phpMyAdmin and the MySQL console, both work. Thus im guessing its something to do with my syntax.

Also, if I get rid of the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` function and parameters it works. However, obviously doesn't update duplicate rows.

Please ask or correct where I am wrong. Thanks.

EDIT: REQUESTED SQL

```
INSERT INTO 
 propertyrating 
 (
   id,
   name
 ) 
VALUES 
 (
   '3',
   '3 Star'
 ) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
name = VALUES (name),
description = VALUES (description)
```

AS REQUESTED UNIQUE * PK

```
Table is as follows:
```

id int UNIQUE AND PRIMARY KEY
 name varchar(100)
 description text

OK GUYS ERROR RETURNED:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATEname = name,description = description
```

as you can see there is no space between UPDATE and name (it reads, UPDATEname) i added a character space and now all is gravy.

Many thanks for getting me to `mysqli_error($link)`

not sure how to give answer to zerkms  but u all led me in the right direction, first.

Code now stands as:

```
$r = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO propertyrating (id,name)" 
                        ."VALUES (\'$ratingid\',\'$rating\')\n"
            ."ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE\n"
            ."name = VALUES (name),\n"
            ."description = VALUES (description)\n"
            . "") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: Replace `\n` with space and show us **plain sql query** (without any php code) generated by your script.

Comment: What about `echo mysqli_error($link);` right after `mysqli_query`?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?  That query looks fine to me...  Do you have a `UNIQUE` on (`name`) by any chance?  Something else is going on, since the query looks to be fine there...

Comment: Yeah, the error would be useful here.

Comment: coming up guys - what is the correct way to catch an error for this query?

Comment: @claw: remove the UNIQUE key.  I asked if you had one.  Not if it was unique.  What's the string of the error?  Or what makes you think there's an error?

Comment: hey guys please see my OP edit. sorry ircmaxwell i missunderstood your question. seems to be working now. many thaqnks for getting my to trap my error

Comment: @zerkms please add your comment as an answer i will grant you the holy green tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `echo mysqli_error($link);` right after `mysqli_query` to get the exact error happened (if any)

But make sure you've removed this line after this debugging session.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to answer without seeing the error you are getting, but I think that you should not include this clause:

```
description = VALUES (description)
```

VALUES(name) returns the value given in the INSERT, and you didn't provide one for description.  Leaving it out will cause description to not be updated.